# Как определить что это карта МИР или другая? jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Прочитал что для валидации используется `luhn-алгоритм`, мне нужно лишь понимать это VISA или MIR.

Подскажите, как имея `input` и событие `input` правильно построить логику таким образом, чтобы брались первые 4 цифры и на их основе показывалось какая это карта (VISA, MIR, и т.д.)?

Сделал нечто ниже, оно как бы и работает, но:

```
$('.error_text.n').fadeIn(350)
```

показывается и сразу же исчезает, как это пофиксить?

P.S. Почему исчезает я понимаю. Подскажите как пофиксить

```
$(".cardNumber").on("input", function() {
  if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
    if (this.value.length == 4) {   
      if (this.value.slice(0, 4) >= 2200 && this.value.slice(0, 4) <= 2204) {
        //Значит это карта мир. При каждом новом символе это условие выполняется вновь и вновь..
        console.log(this.value.slice(0, 4));
      } else {
        $('.error_text.n').fadeIn(350);
      } 
    }
  }

  if (!this.value) {
    $('.cardNumber').addClass('error_input');
    $('.error_text.n').text('Поле не может быть пустым');
    $('.error_text.n').fadeIn(350);
  } else {
    $('.error_text.n').fadeOut(350);
    $('.cardNumber').removeClass('error_input');

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае дополнительно выполняется блок `else` (см. ниже) при попадании в "Мир":

```
if (!this.value) {
    // этот блок игнорируется
} else {
    // этот блок срабатывает
    $(".error_text.n").fadeOut(350)
    $(".cardNumber").removeClass("error_input")            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос, пока полет нормальный:

```
$(".cardNumber").on("input", function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 4) {
    if (this.value.slice(0, 4) >= 2200 && this.value.slice(0, 4) <= 2204) {
      //Значит это карта мир. При каждом новом символе это условие выполняется вновь и вновь..
      console.log(this.value.slice(0, 4));
    } else {
      $('.error_text.n').text('Ошибка. Вы вводите номер, который не относится к карте МИР.');
      $('.error_text.n').fadeIn(350);
    }
  } else {
    if (!this.value) {
      $('.cardNumber').addClass('error_input');
      $('.error_text.n').text('Поле не может быть пустым');
      $('.error_text.n').fadeIn(350);
    } else {
      $('.error_text.n').fadeOut(350);
      $('.cardNumber').removeClass('error_input');
    }
  }
});
```